# Deleting multiple child components from parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I am trying to build my first simple application which should contain some portofolios and each portofolio should contain some stocks. I want to add the functionality of being able to delete all selected stocks from a portofolio. I have tried to implement that functionality but the program behaves strange. When rendering the stocks it does not reflect the deletion performed, but it just doesn't show the last stocks (i.e. if deleted two of them).

```
class Stock extends  React.Component{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: this.props.name,
            unit_value: this.props.unit_value,
            quantity: this.props.quantity,
            total_value: this.props.total_value,
            selected: false
        }
    }

    isSelected = () =>
    {
        var isSelected = this.state.selected;
        isSelected = !isSelected;
        this.setState({selected: isSelected});
        this.props.selected(this.props.index);
        console.log("you selected me!"+this.props.index)
    };

    remove = () =>
    {
        console.log("I am removing stock with index: "+this.props.index);

        this.props.deleteStock(this.props.index)

    };

    render()
    {
        return (
         <tr>
           <td>{this.state.name}</td>
           <td>{this.state.unit_value}</td>
           <td>{this.state.quantity}</td>
           <td>{this.state.total_value}</td>
           <td><input type={'radio'} onChange={this.isSelected}/></td>
         </tr>
        )
    }
    }


class Portofolio extends React.Component{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        let sum = () =>{
            let stocksSum = 0.0;
            let stocks = this.props.stocks;
            console.log(stocks);
            for(let s in stocks)
            {
                stocksSum = stocksSum + stocks[s]['total_value']
            }

            return parseFloat(stocksSum).toFixed(2);
        };

        this.state = {
            editing: false,
            selected: [],
            stocks: this.props.stocks,

            total: sum()
        }

    }

    deleteStock = (i) => {

        console.log("Removing stock: "+i);
        var arr = this.state.stocks;
        arr.splice(i,1);
        this.setState({stocks: arr})

    };


    deleteStocks = () =>
    {
        let selectedItems = this.state.selected;
        console.log("this items to remove");
        console.log(selectedItems);
        let stocks = this.state.stocks;
        for (let a in selectedItems)
        {
            //stocks.splice(selectedItems[a]-a,1)
            this.deleteStock(selectedItems[a]-a);
            console.log("removed: "+selectedItems[a])
        }

        //this.setState({stocks: stocks})

        console.log("stocks after removal:")
        console.log(stocks)

        let sum = () =>{
            let stocksSum = 0.0
            let stocks = this.state.stocks
            for(let s in stocks)
            {
                stocksSum = stocksSum + stocks[s]['total_value']
            }

            return parseFloat(stocksSum).toFixed(2);
        }

        this.setState({total: sum()})
    }

    remove = () =>
    {
        this.props.deletePortofolio(this.props.index)
    };

    selected = (i) => {
        let arr = this.state.selected
        if (arr.indexOf(i) == -1)
        {
            arr.push(i)
        }
        else
        {
            arr = arr.filter(item => item !== i)
        }

        this.setState({selected: arr})

        console.log(arr)
    }

    eachStock(text,i)
    {
        return (
            <Stock key={i} index={i}
                         name={text['name']} unit_value={text['unit_value']} quantity={text['quantity']}
                       total_value={text['total_value']} selected={this.selected} remove={this.deleteStock}>
            </Stock>
        )
    }

    renderNormal = () =>
    {
        const style = {
            border_bottom: '1px solid #ddd'
        };
        return (
            <div className={'portofolio'}>

                <a  onClick={this.remove} className="close-thik"></a>
                <p/><p/><br/>

                <div> {this.props.children}
                    <div className={'divider'}></div>
                    <label>Show in €</label>
                    <div className={'divider'}></div>
                    <label>Show in $</label>
                </div>
                <p/>
                <br/>

              <table style={{border: '1px solid black'}}>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr style={{border: '1px solid black'}}>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Unit value</th>
                      <th>Quantity</th>
                      <th>Total value</th>
                      <th>Select</th>
                  </tr>
                    {
                        this.state.stocks.map(this.eachStock,this)
                    }
                  </tbody>
              </table>
                <p/>
                <p>Total value of {this.props.children} is {this.state.total}</p>
                <button>Add Stock</button>
                <div className={'divider'}></div>
                <button>Perf graph</button>
                <div className={'divider'}></div>
                <button onClick={this.deleteStocks}>Remove selected</button>
            </div>
        )

    };

  render(){

      if(this.state.editing)
      {
        return this.renderForm()
      }
      else
        return this.renderNormal()

  }
}

class Board extends  React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            portofolios: [{name: 'portofolio1', stocks: [
                    {name: 'stock11', unit_value: 1.1, quantity: 1, total_value: 1.1},
                    {name: 'stock12', unit_value: 1.2, quantity: 1, total_value: 1.2},
                    {name: 'stock13', unit_value: 1.3, quantity: 1, total_value: 1.3}
                ]
            },
                {name: 'portofolio2', stocks: [
                        {name: 'stock21', unit_value: 1.1, quantity: 1, total_value: 1.1},
                        {name: 'stock22', unit_value: 1.2, quantity: 1, total_value: 1.2},
                        {name: 'stock23', unit_value: 1.3, quantity: 1, total_value: 1.3}
                    ]
                },
                {name: 'portofolio3', stocks: [
                        {name: 'stock31', unit_value: 1.1, quantity: 1, total_value: 1.1},
                        {name: 'stock32', unit_value: 1.2, quantity: 1, total_value: 1.2},
                        {name: 'stock33', unit_value: 1.3, quantity: 1, total_value: 1.3}
                    ]
                }

            ]
        }
    }

    add = () =>
    {
        let name = this.refs.portofolio_name.value
        if(name == '')
        {
            alert("Name of Portofolio should not be empty!")
            return
        }

        var portofolio = {name: name, stocks: []};
        var arr = this.state.portofolios;
        arr.push(portofolio);
        this.setState({portofolios: arr})
    };

    removePortofolio = (i) =>
    {
        console.log("Removing portofolio "+i)
        var arr = this.state.portofolios;
        arr.splice(i,1)
        this.setState({portofolios: arr})
    }

    eachPortofolio(text,i)
    {
        //console.log(text['stocks'])
        return (<Portofolio key={i} index={i}
                         deletePortofolio={this.removePortofolio}
                         stocks={text['stocks']}
                         >{text['name']}</Portofolio>)
    }

    render ()
    {
        return (
            <div style={{padding: '2%'}}>
                <div className={'head'}>
                    <table className={'table'}>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Portofolio Name:</td><td><input type={'text'} ref='portofolio_name'/></td>
                            <td><button onClick={this.add.bind(null)}>Add new portofolio</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                {
                    this.state.portofolios.map(this.eachPortofolio,this)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is in eachStock method. Prop key should have unique value and it shouldn't be an array index. The best approach is to use stock unique value or add id to stocks and use it.